# SeekBar to adjust screen brightness not working

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to create an app that allows the user to adjust the screen brightness by way of a SeekBar.

The SeekBar is the child of a RelativeLayout view, all of which overlays the parent view when a button is pressed. So essentially the SeekBar only appears when the button is pressed.

I looked through various tutorials online and followed [this one](http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2014/02/adjust-screen-brightness-in-android.html#.V5yjdaLUVM0), but when I run the app and move the slider, the screen brightness does not change. Nothing at all becomes more dark or bright.

Does anyone know where I have gone wrong? Any help would be appreciated! Additionally, is there any way of doing this without requiring write permissions? Or perhaps is there a way to adjust the brightness of only the overlay view?

EDIT: Comments on error log and testing can be found below the code.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.android.screenbrightness">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000000"
android:paddingBottom="0px"
android:paddingLeft="0px"
android:paddingRight="0px"
android:paddingTop="0px"
tools:context="com.example.android.screenBrightness.MainActivity">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnFront"
    android.contentDescription="@null"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/front" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/overlay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:alpha="0.95"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/brightnessLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Brightness"
        android:textColor="#5c5c5c"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="17sp" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/brightnessBar"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="0"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/brightnessLabel"/>

</RelativeLayout></RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    boolean isFrontOn;
    ImageButton btnFront;
    SeekBar brightnessBar;
    float brightness;
    ContentResolver cResolver;
    RelativeLayout overlayLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnFront = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnFront);
        brightnessBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.brightnessBar);

        cResolver = getContentResolver();
        brightnessBar.setMax(255);
        brightnessBar.setKeyProgressIncrement(1);

        btnFront.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(!isFrontOn)
                    turnFrontOn();
                else
                    turnFrontOff();
           }
        });

        try
        {
            brightness = Settings.System.getInt(cResolver, Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS);
        } catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        int screenBrightness = (int) brightness;
        brightnessBar.setProgress(screenBrightness);

        brightnessBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            int progressVal = 0;

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

                if (progress <= 20)
                    progressVal = 20;
                else
                    progressVal = progress;
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                Settings.System.putInt(cResolver, Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, progressVal);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

EDIT: This continuation is in response to @CyprienAubry 's question about an error log.

I was testing the app on an emulator and my Samsung Note 3 (which cannot work with Android Studio so I have to transfer the apk and install it manually).

On the Samsung Note 3, it asks for camera and write permissions during installation, and there is no change when I move the brightness slider, and I cannot see or do not know how to see if there are any errors since the phone does not work with Android Studio.

Using the emulator, when I click the button to bring on the overlay, these errors appear:

```
07-31 00:37:36.158 2580-2690/com.example.android.screenbrightness E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xae471700
07-31 00:37:38.167 2580-2690/com.example.android.screenbrightness E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xaa0ce310
```

And when I try to move the brightness slider, the app crashed and the following errors appear. I attributed them to not being able to get write permissions on the emulator and so did all my testing on my Samsung Note. But Cyprien's question led me to test the app on my Nexus 7, which I will talk about below. For now, the errors using the emulator:

```
07-31 00:39:11.414 2580-2580/com.example.android.screenbrightness E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
07-31 00:39:11.414 2580-2580/com.example.android.screenbrightness E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
07-31 00:39:11.417 2580-2580/com.example.android.screenbrightness E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.SecurityException: com.example.android.screenbrightness was not granted  this permission: android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS.

at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.call(ContentProviderNative.java:646)
at android.provider.Settings$NameValueCache.putStringForUser(Settings.java:1322)
at android.provider.Settings$System.putStringForUser(Settings.java:1671)
at android.provider.Settings$System.putIntForUser(Settings.java:1776)
at android.provider.Settings$System.putInt(Settings.java:1770)
at com.example.android.screenbrightness.MainActivity$4.onStopTrackingTouch(MainActivity.java:108)
at android.widget.SeekBar.onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar.java:121)
at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.onTouchEvent(AbsSeekBar.java:604)
at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:9294)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2403)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1737)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2765)
at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2364)
at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:9514)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4230)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4096)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3787)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3844)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5922)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5896)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5857)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6025)
at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
at android.os.Looper.loop(L
07-31 00:39:11.417 2580-2580/com.example.android.screenbrightness D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM

--------- beginning of crash
07-31 00:39:11.418 2580-2580/com.example.android.screenbrightness E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.example.android.lights, PID: 2580

java.lang.SecurityException: com.example.android.screenbrightness was not granted  this permission: android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS.

at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.call(ContentProviderNative.java:646)
at android.provider.Settings$NameValueCache.putStringForUser(Settings.java:1322)
at android.provider.Settings$System.putStringForUser(Settings.java:1671)
at android.provider.Settings$System.putIntForUser(Settings.java:1776)
at android.provider.Settings$System.putInt(Settings.java:1770)
at com.example.android.screenbrightness.MainActivity$4.onStopTrackingTouch(MainActivity.java:108)
at android.widget.SeekBar.onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar.java:121)
at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.onTouchEvent(AbsSeekBar.java:604)
at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:9294)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2403)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1737)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2765)
at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2364)
at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:9514)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4230)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4096)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3787)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3844)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5922)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5896)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5857)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6025)
at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
at android.os.Me
```

So on the Nexus 7, when I hook it up to my computer and run the app on it through Android Studio, and when I click the overlay button, there are no errors.

When I try to move the brightness slider, the app crashes and produces the same kind of errors as the emulator does, namely:

```
07-31 08:56:28.260 14030-14030/com.example.android.screenbrightness E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.example.android.screenbrightness, PID: 14030

java.lang.SecurityException: com.example.android.screenbrightness was not granted  this permission: android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS.
```

But in contrast to the Samsung Note, when I transfer the apk over to the Nexus 7 and try to install it manually, the app says that it does not require any special access, and still crashes when I try to move the brightness slider.

Comment: Have you an error log?

Comment: @CyprienAubry Thanks for looking at my post! Have edited the original post to include error logs.